# How do i mark html TRUE in l()

Tags: forms, 8, navigation

In Drupal 7 we have option to mark HTML=>TRUE.

How can i do it in Drupal 8

my code is

```
    $create_icon_path = 'my_icon.png'; //my icon path
    $create_icon = '<img height=15 src = "/' . $create_icon_path . '">';
    $create_earlywarning_url = Url::fromUserInput('/node/5');
    $create_earlywarning = \Drupal::l($create_icon, $create_earlywarning_url);
    return $create_earlywarning;
```

But its printing the

```
"<img height=15 src = "my_create-icon.png">" in <a> tag.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

```
$create_icon_path = 'my_icon.png'; //my icon path
$create_icon = '<img height=15 src = "/' . $create_icon_path . '">';  
$create_earlywarning_url = Url::fromUserInput('/node/5');  
$link_render_array = array(
  '#title' => array(
    '#markup' => $create_icon
  ),
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => $create_earlywarning_url,
);
return \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($link_render_array);
```

Hope this solves it!

Answer (score 1):

The `'html' => TRUE` option from links was [removed](https://drupal.org/node/2273923) from core for a few different reasons.  Read the issue for more information.

One of the keys to understanding Drupal 8 is that you almost never need to explicitly render things or resort to the `\Drupal` class in object oriented code.

When you are in a controller or in any other context when you are returning content to be displayed, leverage render arrays and Drupal will do the right thing:

```
$create_icon_path = '/some/path/my_icon.png';
$create_earlywarning_url = Url::fromUserInput('/node/5');

$build = [
  '#title' => [
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#uri' => $create_icon_path,
    '#width' => 15,
    '#height' => 15,
    '#alt' => 'My Alt Text',
  ],
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => $create_earlywarning_url,
];

return $build;
```

So the key here, is that for the `#title` of the link, you can just make it a render array for an image, and the renderer will figure it out and output everything properly (eg, also include the RDF info if you have that enabled).